# No encuentro manera de hacer lo que quiero en ireport

Tags: java, ireport, jaspersoft

estoy haciendo un programa que tiene que crear un informe en pdf con ciertos valores, el problema es que son 70 valores de los cuales se pueden usar todos o algunos, entonces necesito que se muestren, no importa si es en una o cinco paginas, el problema es que me queda un espacio muy grande entre algunos campos. Adjunto el codigo y si puedo mas tarde la imagen por que no quiere subirse. Ya probe de todo pero no me funciono nada, por eso recurro aca.

Dejo el [archivo .jrxml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J6yvDSKkQjplJgdCWBt7SdzLUWg-88ue/view?usp=sharing) por que es muy largo y la pagina no me deja subirlo.

Esta es la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. La pregunta debe ser autocontenida, no depender de que borres el archivo de tu drive, que los enlaces se rompan, etc. El código va EN la pregunta, como texto. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.